# ¿Es correcto usar "@" para significar femenino/masculino?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, género, neutralidad-de-género

He visto *bienvenid@s* con una *@* para significar *bienvenidos/bienvenidas*.

Casi estoy seguro que he visto otras palabras también en cuales meten *@* para significar masculino/femenino, pero no puedo recordarlas ahorita.

¿Es correcto/aceptable hacer eso, o es solo algo que la gente usa aunque no es correcto gramaticalmente?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

La RAE dijo que no es correcto usar "@" para indicar los dos géneros de una palabra porque el símbolo no es una letra.

Fuente: http://www.europapress.es/cultura/exposiciones-00131/noticia-rae-recuerda-no-correcto-utilizar-incluir-masculino-femenino-no-letra-20131212182810.html

Comment: Bien interesante el artículo. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 9):

Además de la recomendación de la RAE, permitidme añadir unos argumentos por los que yo personalmente estoy en contra de este uso de @:

1. No aporta nada, pues ya existe en castellano una forma para incluir a ambos géneros: en este caso, *bienvenidos*.
2. Dificulta la lectura, levemente para los que no están acostumbrados a su uso, y gravemente para ciertas aplicaciones, por ejemplo:

   - Lectores automáticos para ciegos: un ordenador que procesa un texto y tiene una salida de audio por la que lee, y que en este caso seguramente leería algo como *Sed bienvenidarrobaese a mi casa*, en el mejor de los casos. Obviamente, también los usamos personas no ciegas :-), pero para ellos es más importante.
   - Uso de herramientas informáticas como, por poner un ejemplo que entendamos todos, Google Translate. No traduciría bien un texto que contenga palabras así.
   - En ordenadores y teléfonos, aparición de la palabra como si fuera un hipervínculo, al interpretarlo el aparato como una dirección de correo electrónico.

Por motivos sobre los cuales cada uno tendrá su opinión, de un tiempo a esta parte muchas personas y organizaciones, comenzaron a usar términos como:

- Bienvenid@s
- Bienvenidxs
- Bienvenidos y bienvenidas

Yo, aunque paradójicamente suelo estar de acuerdo con muchas de ellas, discrepo totalmente en esto, por lo expuesto en el punto 1 de esta respuesta. Pero de elegir una forma, que sea al menos la tercera (*bienvenidos y bienvenidas*), puesto que es la única que se puede leer y elimina los problemas del punto 2.

Comment: +1 por _bienvenidos_, no he escuchado antes la palabra "bienvenidas", pero sí uso la "palabra" _tod@s_.

Answer (score 1):

Tree House dijo y no mal dijo :""La RAE dijo que no es correcto usar "@" para indicar los dos géneros de una palabra porque el símbolo no es una letra.""

Estoy muy de acuerdo, en este caso, con la RAE. Veo peligroso que se empiecen a adoptar formas o símbolos cortos derivados de Internet para expresar cosas tan importantes como el género masculino o femenino. Las lenguas son formas complejas , con mucho poso y tiempo, que han de resistir a la tentación de lo inmediato, que es, por desgracia, el tipo de comunicación mediocre y parcial que ofrece el nuevo pardigma -que habría que empezar a criticar con dureza- de la comunicación entre humanos por medio de máquinas ordenadoras electrónicas binarias.

Otro ejemplo de intrusión de nuevos símbolos, que yo considero intempestivo, es el uso de los emoticones, para expresar nuestras emociones.Yo me he negado siempre a utilizarlos en Internet y siempre he reprochado a gente con inquietudes literarias, en español o en francés, que los utilizaran. Uno imagina muy mal a Cervantes, poniendo un triste y abusivo emoticon de sonrisa al final de la frase que dirige a Sancho : "Come poco y cena más poco, que la salud de todo el cuerpo se forja en las oficinas del estómago", una de las noches en que precisamente no tenían ni para cenar en buenas condiciones. ¿ Debí yo de haber puesto un emoticon de sonrisa después de : "Tree House dijo y no mal dijo" ?  Hemos de ser capaces de escribirlo todo con las 26 o 27 letras del abecedario; como siempre ha sido, y si ello es preciso, con algún neologismo fundamentado, bien construido y bien equilibrado.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo globalmente excepto por los emoticones. ¿Has visto ya emoticones en la narración de una novela? Los emoticones se usan en contextos muy específicos, no en prosa literaria. Son contextos diferentes.

Comment: Calro que son contextos distintos. Sin embargo la fuerza del nuevo paradigma de la comunicación por máquinas electrónicas, es tal, que hay que ir alertando ya a la gente sobre las consecuencias negativas, no sólo sobre el lenguaje, sino también sobre el propio pensamiento humano.

Comment: Let's continue this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1792/la-tertulia)